# A curious dice rolling experiment

Tags: probability

I have $N$ fair 6-sided dice. I roll them all at once and note $X_1$ the number of 6's obtained. I remove these $X_1$ dice and roll the remaining ones, if there are any. I note $X_2$ the number of 6's obtained this second roll, and so on.

So I have a sequence $X_1,X_2,...$ and I can define the random variable $S_n=X_1+...X_n$ the number of 6's obtained after $n$ rolls.

The question is, **what law does $S_n$ follow**?

---

By a rather involved calculation using the multinomial expansion formula I found that **the law is binomial**: $P(S_n=s)=\binom{N}{s}p^{N-s}(1-p)^s$ where $p=(\frac{5}{6})^n$. This can also be demonstrated by recurrence, but there is still a calculation to do.

Unsatisfying: the answer is so nice but it appears magically at the end of a calculation.

This leads me to believe there is simple explanation why its binomial. Is there a way to interpret the question which arrives at this answer immediately, **without any calculation**?

Comment: Each $X_i$ follows a binomial distribution with $p=1/6$. For instance, $X_1$ is just the number of observed sixes out of $N$ trials. Since the sum of Binomials can also be shown to be Binomial, the result must hold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$S_n$ simply means the number of dice which have at least a $6$ occuring so far and each dice is independent of each other. If it helps, you can continue tossing the dice that have been removed, but once they are removed, they have been removed regardless of later outcomes.

Probability of having at least a $6$ is equal to the $1$- probability of having no $6$ at all.

$$P(\text{having } \ge 1 \text{ six})=1-\left(\frac56 \right)^n$$

\begin{align}P(S_n=s) &= \binom{N}{s}P(\text{having } \ge 1 \text{ six})^sP(\text{having } 0 \text{ six})^{N-s}\\
&=\binom{N}{s}\left(1-\left(\frac56 \right)^n\right)^s \left(\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^n\right)^{N-s}\\
&=\binom{N}{s}\left(1-p\right)^s p^{N-s}\end{align}